# didSelectRowAtIndexPath Is Not Executing With Custom Cell tableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a tableView with custom cell and when i select a row nothing is happening?

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [arrayOfExpectations count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CustomTableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
    Expectations *expectation = [arrayOfExpectations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.quoteLabel.text = expectation.expText;

    return cell;
    }

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Calculate a height based on a cell
    if(!self.customCell) {
        self.customCell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CustomCell"];
    }

    Expectations *expectation = [arrayOfExpectations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    self.customCell.quoteLabel.text = expectation.expText;
    [self.customCell layoutIfNeeded];

    // Get the height for the cell

    CGFloat height = [self.customCell.contentView systemLayoutSizeFittingSize:UILayoutFittingCompressedSize].height;

    // Padding of 1 point (cell separator)
    CGFloat separatorHeight = 1;

    return height + separatorHeight;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return 100;

}


-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    Expectations *expectation = [arrayOfExpectations objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    expParentID = expectation.expID;

    NSLog(@"PrevID = %@", prevexpParentID);
    NSLog(@"NewID = %@", expParentID);

    [self loadData];

}
```

Comment: are you sure you haven't blocked selecting option on a cell?

Comment: Did you set the class of the custom cell in the prototype cell in storyboard?

Comment: how do i set the class of the custom cell in the prototype cell in the storyboard?

Comment: Class is set to CustomTableViewCell

Comment: where do i check if blocked selection option is on cell?

Comment: Did you properly set a delegate for the tableView, either in storyboard or in code?

Answer (score 0):

Selecting option was blocked. Thank you viper king